# F# Type Providers: can you use a type provider in the same project in which it is defined?

Tags: .net-core, f#

I've followed the tutorial about F# type providers [there](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2015-02-06-writing-a-fsharp-type-provider), source code available [here](https://gist.github.com/aaronpowell/74c4bc0315c2e1b42b48).

`Program.fs`:

```ml
open System.Reflection
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices
open ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes

[<TypeProvider>]
type StringTypeProvider(config: TypeProviderConfig) as this =
    inherit TypeProviderForNamespaces(config)

    let namespaceName = "Samples.StringTypeProvider"
    let thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    let staticParams = [ProvidedStaticParameter("value", typeof<string>)]

    let t = ProvidedTypeDefinition(thisAssembly, namespaceName, "StringTyped", Some typeof<obj>, hideObjectMethods = true)

    do t.DefineStaticParameters(
        parameters = staticParams,
        instantiationFunction = (fun typeName paramValues ->
            match paramValues with
            | [| :? string as value |] ->
                let ty = ProvidedTypeDefinition(
                            thisAssembly,
                            namespaceName,
                            typeName,
                            Some typeof<obj>
                        )

                let lengthProp = ProvidedProperty(
                                    "Length",
                                    typeof<int>,
                                    getterCode = fun _ -> <@@ value.Length @@>
                                )
                ty.AddMember lengthProp

                let charProps = value
                                    |> Seq.map(fun c ->
                                            let p = ProvidedProperty(
                                                        c.ToString(),
                                                        typeof<char>,
                                                        getterCode = fun _ -> <@@ c @@>
                                                    )
                                            let doc = sprintf "The char %s" (c.ToString())
                                            p.AddXmlDoc doc

                                            p
                                        )
                                    |> Seq.toList
                ty.AddMembersDelayed (fun () -> charProps)

                let sanitized = value.Replace(" ","")
                let valueProp = ProvidedProperty(
                                    sanitized,
                                    typeof<string>,
                                    getterCode = fun _ -> <@@ value @@>
                                )
                valueProp.AddXmlDoc "This is the value that you gave me to start with"
                ty.AddMember valueProp

                let ctor = ProvidedConstructor(
                            parameters = [],
                            invokeCode = fun args -> <@@ value :> obj @@>
                        )

                ctor.AddXmlDoc "Initializes a the awesomes"

                ty.AddMember ctor

                let reverser = ProvidedMethod(
                                    methodName = "Reverse",
                                    parameters = [],
                                    returnType = typeof<string>,
                                    invokeCode = (fun _ ->
                                                    <@@
                                                    value
                                                        |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.ToString())
                                                        |> Seq.toList
                                                        |> List.rev
                                                        |> List.reduce (fun acc el -> acc + el)
                                                    @@>))

                ty.AddMember reverser

                ty
            | _ -> failwith "No idea what you're doing"
        )
    )

    do this.AddNamespace(namespaceName, [t])
[<assembly:TypeProviderAssembly>]
do()

open Samples.StringTypeProvider

type snowman = Samples.StringTypeProvider.StringTyped< @"☃" >
let doYouWantToBuildASnowman = snowman()
doYouWantToBuildASnowman.``☃``

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    0
```

I have the errors below:

```
  <FSharpPlayground>\Program.fs:3819 The namespace or module 'Samples' is not defined.
  <FSharpPlayground>\Program.fs:3862 The namespace or module 'Samples' is not defined.
  <FSharpPlayground>\Program.fs:3975 The type 'Object' does not define the field, constructor or member '☃'.
```

Which makes sense but is there a workaround to be able to use the F# Type Provider defined in the same project in which it is defined?

[EDIT 1]

Even if I put the whole `StringTypeProvider` definition into another file with `namespace Samples.StringTypeProvider` and then import it in `Program.fs` with `open Samples.StringTypeProvider` it does not work out.

For instance, typing `type snowman = Samples.StringTypeProvider.StringTyped< @"☃" >`, I'm getting:

```
Program.fs(3, 43): [FS0039] The type 'StringTyped' is not defined in 'Samples.StringTypeProvider'. Maybe you want one of the following:
   StringTypeProvider
```

[EDIT 2]

I tried to separate the type provider definition and the place where it is used, but I'm still getting errors: https://github.com/ehouarn-perret/Issues.TypeProviders

Comment: It appears that you do not, in fact, define a module or a namespace named `Samples`, just like the errors say. Is it supposed to come from a different file?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I edited my post, long story short, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you indeed defining a type named `StringTyped` within the `Samples.StringTypeProvider` namespace?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin nope `StringTyped` is defined in `Program.fs`

Comment: First, I don't see in your code where it is defined. Second, if it's not defined within the `Samples.StringTypedProvider`, then why are you trying to reference it as if it was defined there?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin  `Samples.StringTypeProvider.StringTyped< @"☃" >`
this is the whole purpose of a type provider... that create types at compile type.

Comment: FYI ` let t = ProvidedTypeDefinition(thisAssembly, namespaceName, "StringTyped", Some typeof<obj>, hideObjectMethods = true)`

Comment: Ohhh, I suddenly see what you're trying to do. The type provider needs to be in a separate assembly. It needs to be compiled _before_ the assembly that consumes it, so that the F# compiler can run the type provider while compiling the consuming assembly.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yea that's why I was wondering if there is a workaround ^^"""
Sorry if it was not clear from the get-go

Comment: The compiler cannot run the code before it is compiled. The type provider needs to be compiled before it can provide types.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin got it... thought things could be achieved with a bit reflection and calling the compiler through the code... =|

Comment: @FyodorSoikin actually I tried to have a separate library so that the compiler can compile it before using that lib in another console project: https://github.com/ehouarn-perret/Issues.TypeProviders 
still not working